# Unexpected return type of Acid State query (Happstack)

Tags: haskell, happstack, acid-state

I'm trying to extend [Happstack crash course](http://www.happstack.com/docs/crashcourse/index.html) blog with some additional functionality: displaying a list of all tags on home page.

My blog record looks like this:

```
data Blog = Blog
    { nextPostId :: PostId
    , posts      :: IxSet Post
    , allTags    :: [Text] 
    }
    deriving (Data, Typeable)
```

I get blog post by id in the following way (copypasted from crash course):

```
-- Models.hs

postById :: PostId -> Query Blog (Maybe Post)
postById pid =
     do Blog{..} <- ask
        return $ getOne $ posts @= pid

-- Controller.hs

viewPage :: AcidState Blog -> ServerPart Response
viewPage acid = 
     do pid <- PostId <$> lookRead "id"
        mPost <- query' acid (PostById pid)
        ...
        -- mPost has type Maybe Post here
        ...
```

And it works alright.

When I try to do querying of all tags in the similar way:

```
-- Models.hs 

getTags :: Query Blog [Text]
getTags = 
    do Blog{..} <- ask
       return allTags

-- Controller.hs

serveTags :: AcidState Blog -> [Text]
serveTags acid = query' acid GetTags
```

It won't work. The error stack trace is:

```
Blog/Controllers.hs:154:18:
   Couldn't match type `[Text]' with `Text'
   Expected type: [Text]
   Actual type: [acid-state-0.8.1:Data.Acid.Common.EventResult
                                       GetTags]
   In the return type of a call of query'
   In the expression: query' acid GetTags
```

I can't figure out why the return type of `query'` is `[EventResult GetTags]`, while it should be `[Text]`.

What is the reason for this error? Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: That error message suggests to me that `EventResult` is a type function, and `EventResult GetTags` is `[Text]`, when you're assuming it should be `Text`.

Comment: The fact that the package name is mentioned in the type error is worrying. I suspect that multiple versions of acid-state are being involved somehow. Check your package database for sanity, include more details about your compilation process (are you using Cabal? what arguments are you supplying?)

Comment: Just wanted to leave this here: thanks for improving the acid-state tutorial!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your type signature on the `serveTags` function, it should be monadic:

```
serveTags :: MonadIO m => AcidState Blog -> m [Text]
serveTags acid = query' acid GetTags
```

`EventResult` is a type family that here resolves to `[Text]`.  Since `query'` is monadic, your type signature got resolved to the list monad, i.e. `m Text` where the `m` is the list monad, thus the confusing error message.

Comment: Thanks! But if I need to get `[Text]`, how it should be done?

Comment: Simply use do notation to get at the actual value, i.e. `tags <- serveTags acid`.

Comment: Unfortunately I have problem with this: when I try to do something like:    
    `arrangeTags :: AcidState Blog -> [Text]
     arrangeTags acid = 
     do t <- serveTags acid 
        return t`
I'm getting `No instance for (MonadIO []) arising from a use of 'serveTags'` message.

Comment: You can't escape IO in Haskell. `do x <- y; return x` is the same as `y`, so your `arrangeTags` here is just an alias for `serveTags`. It must have the same type, and it must involve `MonadIO m => m ...`. Note that `ServerPart` in Happstack is in fact an instance of `MonadIO` so you can simply use `serveTags` with do-notation directly in a Happstack handler, just like `query' acid (PostById pid)` was used in the crash course example.